# Como copiar arquivo .php

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma base de dados com os campos: nome
Tenho um arquivo a.php que vai buscar os dados nome ao mysql e preenche em determinada zona da página (conteudo).

O que pretendo é que enquanto existirem dados na base de dados na coluna "nome" o ficheiro a.php seja copiado X vezes, alterando o seu nome e conteudo.

Exemplo: o ficheiro A.php é copiado para ana.php e altera o conteúdo da própria página para "Ana"

Como posso fazê-lo?

Comment: Desculpe-me se entendi errado, mas o que está tentando fazer parece ser gambiarra. Poderia detalhar qual é sua aplicação e o que exatamente está querendo fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso com o [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php) e [`fwrite`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fwrite.php):

```
<?php
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ //Onde $query possui um objeto mysqli_result
        $nome = $row['nome'];
        $arquivo = fopen("$nome.php", "w");
        fwrite($arquivo, $nome);
        fclose($arquivo);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Francisco. 
Como devo fazer em relação a editar o conteudo do ficheiro?

Comment: O `fwrite` escreve no arquivo.

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez francisco. Vou fazer o teste para ver como corre :)